# Highchart can't be displayed

Tags: highcharts

I have problems with HighChart. It it not displayed yet ... But jquery.js, highcharts.js and so on are loaded. What can be the error?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="../js/highcharts.js "></script>
<script type="javascript">

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {        renderTo: 'container2'    },
    xAxis: {    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] },
    series: [{   data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] }]
});

</head>
</script>
<body>
<div id="container2" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 2em"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the console show you when you run it?

Comment: @wergeld Nothing - All seems perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load chart after DOM is ready:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {        renderTo: 'container2'    },
        xAxis: {    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] },
        series: [{   data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Two more bugs in your code: 1) `</head>
</script>` <--- should be first closed script, then head, right? 2) `<script type="javascript">` <--- set text/javascript.

Comment: You have beautified my life!